# How to redirect from one CGI to another

Tags: perl, cgi

I am sending data from `A.cgi` to `B.cgi`. `B.cgi` updates the data in the database and is supposed to redirect back to `A.cgi`, at which point `A.cgi` should display the updated data. I added the following code to `B.cgi` to do the redirect, immediately after the database update:

```
$url = "http://Travel/cgi-bin/A.cgi/";
print "Location: $url\n\n";
exit();
```

After successfully updating the database, the page simply prints

```
Location: http://Travel/cgi-bin/A.cgi/
```

and stays on `B.cgi`, without ever getting redirected to `A.cgi`. How can I make the redirect work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Location:` is a header and headers must come before all ordinary output, that's probably your  problem. But doing this manually is unneccessarly complicated anyways, you would be better of using the [redirect function of CGI.pm](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER)

Answer (score 1):

Use CGI's [redirect](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html#GENERATING-A-REDIRECTION-HEADER) method:

```
my $url = "http://Travel/cgi-bin/A.cgi";
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->redirect($url);
```